# Fetch a string between a static pattern in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

script that will extract string between a particular pattern in HTML file.

Example:
suppose if the HTML text has:

```html
<p translate="index_word1" > </p>
```

Output should be:
`index_word1`

Basically want a string between translate="**this string**".

Comment: Sorry but you need to show us what you have tried first, please post your [mcve] and explain what problem you are facing in your implementation.

Comment: I'm assuming the serial downvoter is because none of the answers "reads a file" - you've essentially asked two questions "how to read a file" "how to parse a string" - everyone has answered the only sensible question.  The other is a huge security risk (assuming client js and not node.js which wasn't in the tags).

Comment: all the answers below are working as per requirement hence i have upvoted the working answers. but have given a accepted answer to the optimised code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DOMParser` to convert the string to a document, after which you could `querySelectorAll` over it to find the elements with `translate` attributes:

```js
const str = `<p translate="index_word1" > </p>
<strong translate="index_word2"></strong>`;
new DOMParser()
  .parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
  .querySelectorAll('[translate]')
  .forEach(element => console.log(element.getAttribute('translate')));
```

Comment: It worked as required, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case your match would be `m[1]`

```js
const regex = /translate="(.+)"/gm;
const str = `<p translate="index_word1" > </>
<strong translate="index_word2"></strong>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
    // Your case
    console.log(`Your case: ${m[1]}`)
}
```

Comment: working as per question's requirement. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to extract the `translate` attributes:

```
$("[translate]").map(function(i, el) { return $(this).attr("translate"); }
```

Example reading from a string:

```js
var s = '<p translate="index_word1"><p/><strong translate="index_word2"></strong>';

var html = $("<div>").append(s);
var arr = $("[translate]", html).map(function(i, el) { return $(this).attr("translate"); }).toArray();
console.log(arr);

$.each(arr, function(i) { $("#out").append(arr[i] + "<br/>"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: working as per question's requirement. thanks